Procedure for Tauc plot from opaque sample
I would like to estimate the bandgap of a material and I would like to know if there is anything wrong with the following process,
I will estimate band gap from a Tauc plot. For the Tauc plot I would like to plot:
$$ (\alpha h \nu )^{1/2}$$ against the photon energy.
The sample in question is opaque and polished. It is opaque so I cannot directly obtain the absorption data by measuring both transmittance and reflectance data. All I can measure reflectance data.
I have seen that people sometimes use diffuse reflectance and the Kubelka-Monk transformation to obtain the absorption coefficient, but I think it does not apply as I am measuring the normal incidence reflectance from a polished surface.
Instead, I used a KK transformation to obtain the extinction coefficient, k, from the reflectance data. This a software procedure provided by the spectrometer.
The absorption coefficient is related to the optical extinction coefficient by
$$ \alpha = 4\pi k / \lambda_0 $$
Where $\lambda_0$ is the vacuum/air wavelength light.
Does this seem right? When I look up how to find bandgap of a sample it seems like the processes are often expecting a diffuse reflection spectrum.
